# xkk symbols remapping not working in terminal

Tags: linux, zsh, key-bindings, archlinux, oh-my-zsh

I edited my `usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file so that I can use h, j, k, l, 0, and $ keys like we use them in Vim. everything is working as expected except in terminal commands. I also tried using them in Vim in insert mode and they are working just fine even though it is still working under a terminal emulator environemtn.

If I try to use it, it replaces my movement with this:
h:D
j:B
k:A
l:C
0:H
$:F

I'm using `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` by the way.

Here is my `us` edited part:

```
//start of caps ihjkl;
    key <AC06> {    [     h,    H,             Left     ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [     j,    J,             Down     ]   };
    key <AC08> {    [     k,    K,             Up       ]   };
    key <AC09> {    [     l,    L,             Right    ]   };
    key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenright,    Home     ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [     4,    dollar,        End      ]   };

    key <CAPS> {    [     ISO_Level3_Shift              ]   };
```

this is inside the `xkb_symbols "basic"` block.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "terminal environment", do you mean using a terminal emulator (e.g. xterm/gnome-terminal), or are you pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 (or another number) to reach a virtual terminal? Since you're changing X11 settings, they should work in a terminal emulator, but not in a virtual terminal.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself, "terminal environment" I was meaning a terminal emulator.

Comment: Then I don't really have any ideas to help. You may want to specify what terminal emulator you use on the question, and try it on different ones to check if the problem is specific to that terminal emulator or not.

Comment: I actually did that, I tried Konsole, Terminator and Guake dropdown Terminal. Thanks

Comment: @Yasser : I hope you did set your shell to `vi` mode, did you?

Comment: @user1934428 no I didn't. and that's a great fix that I don't know how it didn't occur to me. However, I'm still curious to know why did the terminal acts differently?

Comment: The shell runs a line editor, which needs to react on your keys to position the cursor. By default, the modes `emacs` and `vi` are offered. AFIK most people (including me) use _emacs_, and maybe that's the default. You can use `set -o vi` to explicitly request _vi_  mode.

Comment: @user1934428 I used the `vi-mode` plugin with `oh-my-zsh` and it offers a lot more than the native `zsh vi mode` does. I'm trying to figure out how to bind `ii` to go out of `insert mdoe`. Thanks a lot!